# $\gamma: \left[ -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] \to \mathbb C$, $\gamma (t) = 2e^{it}$. Calculate: $\int_{\gamma} \frac{z}{z^2 + 1} dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Let $\gamma: \left[  -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] \to \mathbb C$ be given by $\gamma (t) = 2e^{it}$. Calculate
> $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{z}{z^2 + 1} dz$$
> by finding area $U$ containing $\gamma^* = \gamma \left( \left[   -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] \right) $ and an antiderivative $F$ of function $f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2 + 1}$ on area $U$. Use the equality: $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = F(\gamma(\frac{\pi}{2})) - F(\gamma(-\frac{\pi}{2})).$

Now I can find the antiderivative. It is just $\frac{\ln(z^2 + 1)}{2}$. The problem is that $\gamma (t) = 2e^{it}$ is a ring around $0$ and there is no way to cover that area with logarithm. So I need to somehow merge more than one area to get my $U$. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: No such thing exists, as it is a closed ring. There is such a thing as patching together open sets to define continuous logarithms, but it’s impossible to do on a ring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at $f(z) = \frac z{z^2+1}$, we can easily observe it has singularities at $z = \pm i$. So, it is holomorphic on open subsets of $\mathbb C$ that don't contain these points.

As you observe, the obvious candidate for antiderivative $z\mapsto\frac 12 \log(z^2+1)$ is problematic since $z\mapsto z^2+1$ will map semicircle $\gamma^*$ onto a circle around $0$. But we can use a bit of trickery and write
$$\frac12 \log(z^2+1) = \frac12 \log(z^2(1+1/z^2)) = \frac 12\log(1+1/z^2) + \log z.$$
Direct calculation shows that $$\frac d{dz}\left( \frac 12\log(1+1/z^2) + \log z \right) = \frac z{z^2+1},$$ but we avoid the problem from before since $z\mapsto 1+1/z^2$ maps semicircle $\gamma^*$ onto the circle centred at $1$, but with radius $1/4$ instead of $4$. So, we can use
$$F(z) = \frac 12\log(1+1/z^2) + \log z$$ to evaluate your integral to be $\pi i$.

To find appropriate open $U$, note that for $\log(1+1/z^2)$ we simply need $|z|>1$ and for $\log z$ exclude appropriate ray, such as the negative real axis.

---

Alternatively, by using substitution $w = z^2 + 1$, we can see that your integral is $\frac 12 \int_\Gamma \frac{dw}w$ where $\Gamma$ is a circle around $0$, which is well known to evaluate to $\frac 12 \cdot 2\pi i$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints to solve this problem.
First note that by "symmetry of path and function $f$" (this expression needs to become a bit more rigor by you!) then can be concluded that $$∮_{\gamma_1} f(z)dz = \frac{1}{2}∮_{\gamma_2} f(z)dz$$
where $$\gamma_1= 2e^{it} : t\in [\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$$
$$\gamma_2= 2e^{it} : t\in [\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$$
and finally following lemma from Stein's book "Complex Analysis" will help you to finish the job:

> **Corollary2.3**:Suppose that f is holomorphic in an open set containing a toy >contour γ and its interior, except for poles at the points $z_1,...,z_N$ inside γ. Then
> $$∮_{\gamma} f(z)dz = 2\pi i\sum res_{z_k}f$$
> where the right hand side is residue of $f$ at $z_k$ and $z_k$ is a pole for f and 
> $$res_{z_k}f = \lim_{z \to z_k} (z-z_k)f(z)$$